# asyncio.queue strange behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

This code

```
import asyncio


@asyncio.coroutine
def foo(q):

    print("foo before", q.empty())
    q.put_nowait("yoba")
    print("foo after", q.empty())


@asyncio.coroutine
def bar(q):

    for _ in range(5):

        asyncio.async(foo(q))
        r = yield from q.get()
        print("bar received", r)


q = asyncio.Queue()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(bar(q))
```

Produce this output:

```
foo before True
foo after True
bar received yoba
foo before True
foo after True
bar received yoba
foo before True
foo after True
bar received yoba
foo before True
foo after True
bar received yoba
foo before True
foo after True
bar received yoba
```

Why queue become empty, even when I did not `yield from` and flow control did not return to loop? I expect, that elements will not "pop" from queue until I will return flow control to loop and it decide to "pop" data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the source of `asyncio.Queue.put_nowait`:

```
if self._getters:
    assert not self._queue, (
        'queue non-empty, why are getters waiting?')

    getter = self._getters.popleft()
    self.__put_internal(item)

    # getter cannot be cancelled, we just removed done getters
    getter.set_result(self._get())
```

As we can see, if at least one `get()` is not fulfilled, any call to `put_nowait()` will put an item into the queue, then pop it **immediately**, giving no chance for the queue to be in a nonempty state.

Comment: Oh, messy… anyway, thanks for answer, I think about it, but can't believe, that this is true. So sometimes you put and it not empty, but sometimes it empty -_-